# Проблема с методами begin и end

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct keker{
   int a;
   int b;
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

   set<keker> rofl;
   keker k1,k2,k3,k4;

   k1.a = 1;
   k2.a = 2;
   k3.a = 3;
   k4.a = 4;

   rofl.insert(k1);
   rofl.insert(k2);
   rofl.insert(k3);
   rofl.insert(k4);

   cout<< rofl.begin()->a<<endl;
   cout<< rofl.end()->a<<endl;

   return 0;

}
```

После компиляции выводит:
    1
    1

Хотя должен выводить:
    1
    4

Помогите, пожалуйста, уже весь день маюсь с этим

Comment: В коде примера отсутствует код оператора сравнения (<) для keker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот тут

```
 rofl.end()->a
```

он вообще может делать что хочет: разыменовывать итератор, возвращаемый `end()`, нельзя!

Это - **не** последний элемент в контейнере, это итератор, указывающий, грубо говоря, **за** контейнер!

Все, для чего он пригоден - это для сравнения с ним значения другого итератора - типа, проход по контейнеру завершен или там элемент не найден.

Но не для разыменования!

Comment: Хорошо, я сделал так: auto it = rofl.begin(); it++; cout<<rofl.begin()->a; cout<< it->a; И все равно выводит 1 1 , хотя должен выводить 1 2. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы так уверенно написали, что он выводит что-то, что я решил, что вы просто забыли указать в коде оператор `<` для вашего типа `keker`, но у вас он имеется. Ведь ваш код просто не компилируется без него - http://ideone.com/DG005R - `set` должен знать, **как** упорядочивать элементы. А вот если вы добавите этот оператор, то все будет в порядке: http://ideone.com/6RRU99 Простите, конечно, но у вас код точно вот такой, как вы показали?

Comment: А , все понял, видимо я не до конца прочитал про set